# Why does my heroku bash instance show my app folder to be empty?

Tags: python, django, bash, heroku

I've deployed an app to heroku and ran `heroku run bash -a {app_name}`
Once it successfully opens a bash console and I run `ls` I see nothing.
If I run `pwd` it says I'm in the `/app` directory where my project files should be.

---

I am also unable to run any commands using my `manage.py` file e.g. `heroku run python manage.py migrate` results in a `python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`